# DNS Redirect Clarification

Tags: dns, redirect

We have old domain name which we would like to redirect the traffic to new domain

e.g.

**old.domain.com --> new.domain.com**

Help/Clarification:

1. What's the best way to achieve this? Read about CName, ARecord, Alias etc., therefore confused which one to use and which scenario.
2. If we redirect old.domain.com to new.domain.com, then what will IIS/Web Server see as requested host name i.e. still sees old.domain.com or new.domain.com

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect the traffic, i.e., you want the customer's web browser to show the change from "old.domain.com" to "new.domain.com", then you'll need to insert that redirect at the web server or code level.

If you simply want a request for "old.domain.com" to land on the address for "new.domain.com", then you can use just a CNAME in DNS.

Comment: Wonder when to use CName vs. A Record vs. Alaises

Comment: A CNAME is a DNS level redirect; i.e., a way to point nameA at a different name. An A record is the IP that a name is translated to.

Often, you would want a CNAME for a service level entry, like mail.example.com or www.example.com. This can then CNAME to a specific server record like webserver01.example.com. The reason this is useful is because, also often, you will need to change the server behind the service, but you don't want customers to have to use a different name.